# Making a program that matches user input with a 'database'. Keep getting this error

Tags: c++

Can't figure whats the problem, I suspect the array of objects is not populated correctly. After i enter the movie title then i get this error  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cctype>

using namespace std; 

struct Movie
{
    string Title; // Movie title 
    string Gross; // Gross total in billion dollars 
    string Director; // Director name 
    string Date; // Release date 
    string Runtime; // Runtime in minutes 
};

int numberOfLines(ifstream&);
void populateMovieFromFile(ifstream&, Movie&);
void displayMovie(const Movie&);
Movie* createDatabase(int&);
bool caseInsensitiveCmp(string, string);
void findMovie(Movie*, int);
void saveToFile(const Movie&);
bool promptToContinue();
//void displayFavorites();

int main ()
{
    int number_Of_Lines = 0;
    Movie* ptr_movies = createDatabase(number_Of_Lines); 
    do
    {
        findMovie(ptr_movies , number_Of_Lines);
    }while (!promptToContinue());
    //displayFavorites();
    return 0;
}

int numberOfLines(ifstream& movie_file)
{
    int number_Of_Lines = 0; 
    string lines;
    if(movie_file)
    {
        while(getline(movie_file, lines))
            number_Of_Lines++ ; 
    }
    movie_file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    return number_Of_Lines;
}

void populateMovieFromFile(ifstream& movie_file, Movie& movies)
{
    getline(movie_file, movies.Title, ',');
    movie_file.ignore();
    getline(movie_file, movies.Gross, ',');
    movie_file.ignore();
    getline(movie_file, movies.Director, ',');
    movie_file.ignore();
    getline(movie_file, movies.Date, ',');
    movie_file.ignore();
    getline(movie_file, movies.Runtime);

}

void displayMovie(const Movie& movie)
{
    cout << right << setw(13) << "Title: " << left << movie.Title << endl; 
    cout << right << setw(13) << "Gross Total: " << left << movie.Gross << " billion dollars" << endl;
    cout << right << setw(13) << "Director: " << left << movie.Director << endl;
    cout << right << setw(13) << "Release date: " << left << movie.Date << endl; 
    cout << right << setw(13) << "Runtime: " << left << movie.Runtime << " minutes" << endl; 
}

Movie* createDatabase(int& number_Of_Lines)
{
    // input file 
    ifstream movie_file;
    string filename;
    do 
    {
        cout << "Please enter filename: " ;
        getline (cin , filename);
        movie_file.open(filename.c_str());
        if(movie_file.fail())
            cout << "Invalid file" << endl ; 
    }while(movie_file.fail());

    // array of objects
    number_Of_Lines = numberOfLines(movie_file);
    Movie* ptr = new Movie [number_Of_Lines]; 

    //Looping through array of objects 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < number_Of_Lines ; i++)
        populateMovieFromFile(movie_file, ptr[i]);

    return ptr; 
}
```

Ran through the debugger, input[i] doesn't have value.

```
bool caseInsensitiveCmp(string input, string list) //list will be from the object of array 
{
    int i = 0 , j = 0;
    while (input[i])
    {
        char c = input[i]; 
        input[i] = tolower(c); 
        i++;
    }
    while (list[j])
    {
        char c = list[j]; 
        list[j] = tolower(c); 
        j++;
    } 
    if (input == list)
        return true;    
    else 
        return false;
}

void findMovie(Movie* ptr_movie, int number_Of_Lines)
{
    cout << endl; 
    int i = 0;
    char save; 
    string input_title; 
    bool found = false; 
    bool No_Match = false;
    cout << "Enter a movie title to search for: ";
    getline(cin , input_title);
    do
    {
        found = caseInsensitiveCmp(ptr_movie[i].Title , input_title); //loop it
        if (found == false)
            i++; 
        if (i>=number_Of_Lines)
            No_Match = true;
    } while (found == false || No_Match == false);

    if(found == true)
    {
        displayMovie(ptr_movie[i]);
        cout << endl ;
        cout << "Would you like to save the above movie? (Y or N)" << endl;
        cin >> save; 
        if (save == 'y' || save == 'Y')
            saveToFile(ptr_movie[i]);
    }

    else 
        cout << input_title << " not found in database. Please try again." << endl;
}

void saveToFile(const Movie& movie)
{
    ofstream outfile; 
    outfile.open("favourites.txt", ios::app);
    cout << movie.Title << "," << movie.Gross << "," 
    << movie.Director << "," << movie.Date << "," 
    << movie.Runtime << endl;
}

bool promptToContinue()
{
    char Quit; 
    bool exit = false;
    cout << "Would you like to exit? (Y or N): ";
    cin >> Quit; 
    switch (Quit)
    {
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            exit = true;

        case 'N': 
        case 'n': 
            exit = false;
    }
    return exit;
}
```

Comment: While `std::string` objects are required to terminate their contained strings since the C++11 standard, you should still use other ways to iterate over strings. For example [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Or for some of your loops using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: `bool caseInsensitiveCmp(string input, string list)` -- Do not name your variable `list`, since there is a `std::list` class in C++.

Comment: There is no way to test your program, since we don't have the data file.  You should be unit testing each part of your code first, to make sure it works correctly.  Also, why are you not using `std::vector` here?  You're reading an entire file twice, the first time just to get the number of lines.  If there were a million lines, that's wasted effort.  Using `vector`, all you would need is a single read of the file, calling `push_back` for each line.